# How to add CorePlot release branch 2.3 to current build - CocoaPods assistance

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, core-plot, xcode9, xcode9.2

I just updated my XCode version to 9.2 in order to demo a BLE+iOS app on an iOS 11 phone.

I tried to build to with the new iOS, and I received a bunch of "Implicit conversion from nullable pointer 'NSNumber * ......'

After reading about these common errors with the new XCode and the CorePlot 2.2 release, I read about the 2.3 branch (that can be added to the CocoaPods temporarily before XCode 9.2 is out of beta.)

I am unfamiliar with this process of adding a branch to the CocoaPods, so would anyone be able to walk me through this?

Thanks
-Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following line in your podfile to use the `release-2.3` branch:

```
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.3'
```